# Bootstrap table creates html divs but doesnt populate the data into them

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a table using bootstrap table. It seems that bootstrap creates the correct amount of rows according to my json data input, but it doesn't populate it with the data itself.

```
// Javascript

function getStocksData () {
    $.ajax('getStocksAvailable/', {
        method: 'GET',
        async: "True",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var received_data = response.data;
            console.log(received_data);

            $('#stocksTable').bootstrapTable({
              columns: [{
                field: 'stockName',
                title: 'Company'
              }, {
                field: 'priceLast',
                title: 'Last'
              }],
              data: received_data
            });
        }
    });
};

getStocksData();
```

```
// html

<div id="tableWrapper">
    <table id="stocksTable"></table>
</div>
```

**This is the currently rendered output:**

[image]

**And the json data:**

[image]

Might the format of the json cause the issue, so to say that bootstrap is not able to enter into the indexes of the json items? If so, how to work around this? Any way to remove the id_s from the json in order to enable bootstrap to read the data?

I don't get any errors in the console.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `bootstrapTable` jQuery extension, but looking at your data, I would guess the solution is to replace `data: received_data` with `data: received_data.map(item => item.fields)`

Comment: Are you kidding me? I struggled for hours to get this solution... drinks are on me! Thank you mate!

Comment: No problem, happy to help. Will put this into an answer since you've confirmed it works - it would be nice if you can upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Sure, will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `bootstrapTable` method expects the `data` passed to it to be an array of objects (which yours is), where each object contains the properties specified in the `field` properties of the columns you specify. Unfoe, your data doesn't fit this pattern, as the objects with the properties you want are held within the `fields` property of the top level objects.

If you can't change how your API returns this data, the solution on the javascript side is to use `map` to get those "field" objects to the top level, like this:

```
data: received_data.map(item => item.fields)
```

Comment: do you have an idea why the mapping doesn't work within an Axios function?

Comment: I tried to shift your .map method to a Vue.js app, but it doesn't work :( ... I opened a new thread since it is a slightly different topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61921998/how-to-transform-json-object-into-vue-v-for-compatible-format

Comment: just took a look, the existing comments and answer cover everything I would have said