# How to transform JSON object into Vue v-for compatible format

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to populate a html table using `Vue.js v-for`. However, it doesn't build the table. My guess is that the data input isn't in the right format and thus needs to be mapped/changed to remove the object layer (index of each item).

I tried it using `.map` but it doesn't work.

```
Vue.js

callStocks = function () {
          var app = new Vue({
            delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
            el: "#stocksTable",
            data: {
              stocks: []
            },
            created() {
              axios
                .get("getStocksAvailable/")
                .then(response => {
                    var data = response.data.data
                    this.stocks = data.map(item => item.fields)
                    console.log (data)
                });
            }
          });
};

callStocks();
```

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Company</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="stocksTable">
  <tr>
   <td v-for="item in stocks">[[ item.stockName ]]</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**Console.log:**

[image]

**Vue.js devtool object:**

[image]

Comment: you didn't assign `data` or mapped `data` to `this.stocks`.

Comment: You got me! Changed it, but it seems the mapping doesn't work as intended, I guess I have to get rid of the object IDs in order to enable Vue making its job?

Comment: `data.map(item => item.fields)` does nothing. You should assign `map` result to some var. Like `this.stocks = data.map(item => item.fields)`

Answer (score 0):

Map doesn't mutate the array, it returns a new one.

So either `this.stocks = data.map(item => item.fields)`
or `[[ item.fields.stockName ]]`

Edit: Also, data must be a function

Comment: Appreciate all the support! It seems the mapping now works (see updated post), but it still doesn't render the DOM

Comment: Maybe this is it: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Answer (score 0):

Since you've previously declared `stocks` attribute, you don't need to worry about [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects), however, I believe you should change your template a bit also. Also be careful about [how you write your data](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function).

```
callStocks = function () {
    var app = new Vue({
        delimiters: ["[[", "]]"],
        el: "#stocksTable",
        data: () => ({
          stocks: []
        }),
        created() {
            axios
            .get("getStocksAvailable/")
            .then(response => {
                var data = response.data.data
                this.stocks = data.map(item => item.fields)
                console.log (data)
            });
        }
    });
};

callStocks();
```

Your template is iteration inside a single row, I believe you want to add one stock name per row.

```
...
<tbody id="stocksTable">
  <tr v-for="item in stocks">
    <td>[[ item.stockName ]]</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
...
```

Comment: so should this be included in the axion.then method?

Comment: Just replace your `this.stocks = data.map(item => item.fields)` with it. AFAIK, this is one of the caveats of Vue's reactivity system.

Comment: Done and it doesn't throw a error, but still no html rendering.. I might reach out to Vue.js Forum and post a working solution here if I find one. This is weird -.- Thanks

Comment: Sorry but Vue.set is totally not needed in this case. You replace the whole array so Vue totally gets it.

Comment: @Renaud Didn't saw the previous declaration of `stocks`, thanks!

Comment: @Phanti Check now the code, Renaud pointed correctly, reactivity is not the problem, however check your template as you're creating a single row for all the data.

Comment: I changed it accordingly, thanks. But still it won't loop and render. On pageload it displays the variable in brackets for like a blink of an eye and that's it.